# How to close an expanded div by clicking outside with calling click function for close event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, there are lots of solution for this kinds of problems at here. But, my problem is I am not allowed to edit existing functionality. The existing functionality is:

```
$('body').on('click', '.parent.normal', function () {
  // code for Expanding a div
});
```

and

```
$('body').on('click', '.parent.expand', function () {
  // code for Closing expanded div
});
```

What I can do is defining another `click` function for clicking outside of the expanded div which will call the existing click event for closing expanded div. To do that, I have written this:

```
  if($('.parent.expand').length > 0) {
    $('div:not(".parent.normal, .expanded-content, .expanded-content > div")').click(function () {
      $('.parent.expand').click();
    });
  }
```

Which is not working actually. How can I make it working?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/q89d9go7/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your existing code must fix the issue.

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){   
  if (!$(e.target).parents('.content').length > 0){
     $('.parent.expand').click();
  }
});
```

Here is a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/q89d9go7/7/)

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me if I write $(body).on(...) instead of $(document).on(...) in your code, why won't it work?

Comment: because in that example body height is only upto the expanded div height, Inspect the element and you will notice it. So technically the click is not happening inside the body but outside it

Answer (score 1):

This will do it **without making any changes** in existing functions:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {

   var elem_not = $(".parent.normal, .parent.expand, .expanded-content, .expanded-content > div");

   if (!elem_not.is(e.target) && elem_not.has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('.parent.expand').click();
   }

});
```

Updated your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q89d9go7/6/)

Comment: Thanks! It's a nice solution too

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your css so that your body has 100% width and 100% height. This will create an area for your click events to register outside of the div.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And then use this javascript:

```
// open expand content
$('body').on('click', '.parent.normal', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('normal');
  $(this).addClass('expand');
  $(this).parent().find('.expanded-content').slideDown(300);
});

// close expand content
$('body').on('click', '.parent.expand', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('expand');
  $(this).addClass('normal');
  $(this).parent().find('.expanded-content').slideUp(300);
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.parent.expand').click();
});
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/szznv0h3/22/)

Comment: Thanks for your help